# Throwing exceptions syntax java

Tags: java, illegalargumentexception, throw

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to throw and catch exceptions.
I Think I have the general syntax right, at least according to the book that I'm using, but I keep getting errors.

Can anyone help me out with the syntax?

```
public Movie( String title, int yearReleased, double rating){
    try{
        if (rating < 4.1 && rating >= 0.0)
            this.rating = rating; 
        else
            throw new IllegalArgumentException;
    catch (IllegalArgumentException e){
        System.out.println("This rating is invalid");
    }
}
```

Comment: So, what is the error? Also, double check your curly braces.

Comment: This is so far from compilable code that it might as well be pseudocode. Why can't you _use_ the compiler to find your errors, it has very clear errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two issues:

1) Your closing `}` for the try is inside the `if`.

2) You are not properly calling the constructor of IllegalArgumentException. Do `throw new IllegalArgumentException();

In the future, you should read and try to understand the compiler message. It is most likely telling you exactly what there errors are and where. (That is why your question has been down-voted so much.)

I get that you're new to this so I am more than happy to help you out.

Happy coding.

Comment: whoops sorry! edited to get rid of that extra bracket, I'll try your suggestion right now

Comment: @maribov it doesn't really make sense to post a question, wait for answers to that question, then edit the core of the question now does it?

Comment: My advice is to learn to read compiler messages. You have to do that if you want to get good with Java or any compiled language.

Comment: that wasn't the core of the question, the second part of @todd's answer was the core of the question :)

Comment: the first part was just a typo hehehe

Comment: @Todd all that it was telling me was that "IllegalArgumentException" could not be assigned to a variable in the compiler message

Comment: @maribov Now that you have it working. Put the syntax error back and checkout the compiler error again. That way you recognize it better next time.

Answer (score 0):

The mistakes we're doing while not enclosing brackets..

You have a redundant closing brackets.

```
this.rating = rating; }
```

Please remove it.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
throw new ArgumentException();
```

because it is constructor and you forgot to put parentheses

Comment: why the downvote? throw should be written like this. pls the downvoter explain your logic